# Tikzpicture not showing multiple fillbetween

Tags: tikz-pgf, fillbetween

I have the following code within a beamer presentation:

```
\begin{frame}[c]{ }
\frametitle{Section 5.2: Definite Integral}  


\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale =1]
  \begin{axis}[
    axis lines=center,
    grid=major,
    xmin=-12.5,
    xmax=12.5,
    ymin=-10.5,
    ymax=10.5,
    xtick = {-12,-10,...,12}, 
    ytick = {-10,-8,...,10}, 
    yticklabel style = {font=\tiny,xshift=0.5ex},
    xticklabel style = {font=\tiny,yshift=0.5ex},
    no marks,
    axis line style={thick, <->},  
    ]
\addplot+[-, samples = 200, thin, black, domain = -12:12 , name path=A] {0};          
\addplot+[<-, samples = 200, thick, blue, domain = -11:-4 , name path=B] {0.5*(x + 4) + 4};       
\addplot+[-, samples = 200, thick, blue, domain = -4:-0 , name path=C] {4};   
\addplot+[-, samples = 200, thick, blue, domain = 0:6, name path=D] {-2*x+4};  
\addplot+[->, samples = 200, thick, blue, domain = 6:10.25, name path=E] {4*(x - 6)-8};
\addplot+[red, opacity = 0.3] fill between[of=A and B,soft clip={domain=-8:-4}]; % filling 
\addplot+[red, opacity = 0.3] fill between[of=A and C,soft clip={domain=-4:-0}]; % filling    
\addplot+[red, opacity = 0.3] fill between[of=A and D,soft clip={domain=0:6}]; % filling  
\addplot+[red, opacity = 0.3] fill between[of=A and E,soft clip={domain=6:10}]; % filling                     
\node[blue] at (axis cs:7,7){{\tiny$y = g(t)$}};            
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center} 
\end{frame}
```

which produces the following picture:
[image]

I want to have the entire area under the curve from t = -8 to t = 10 filled, but it is only filling the first portion. How can I fix this?

Comment: Should it fill between the plot and the axis above the 0 for Y? Or any space between plot and axis but between `x -8` and `x 10`? I mean [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEAE0.png)? It's not clear at the moment

Comment: @Alenanno It should. It may be worth mentioning that this code worked correctly and produced that exact image when I ran it on a different computer.

Comment: There's an error in your code, one command says `\addplot ... [of=AA and C`, it should be `A and C`. Also, add `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}`, does it work now?

Comment: @Alenanno Unfortunately no. That is a remnant of a fix a tried that was ultimately unsuccessful. I basically tried to create a second x-axis with path name AA to see if each section having its own x-axis would create the graphic I desired.

Comment: There must be something wrong with your code, try to test one of the two I provided below. If you still get errors, you might need to update your TeX distribution, maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise you to use a single `plot` whenever possible, I replicated yours using the same coordinates (for the imprecise paths, I have superimposed them and they match perfectly). I will give you also the solution with your code, so you can choose.

### Your code

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale =1]
    \begin{axis}[
      axis lines=center,
      grid=major,
      xmin=-12.5,
      xmax=12.5,
      ymin=-10.5,
      ymax=10.5,
      xtick = {-12,-10,...,12}, 
      ytick = {-10,-8,...,10}, 
      yticklabel style = {font=\tiny,xshift=0.5ex},
      xticklabel style = {font=\tiny,yshift=0.5ex},
      no marks,
      axis line style={thick, <->},  
      ]
      \path[name path=axis] (axis cs:-10,0) -- (axis cs:12,0);
    \addplot+[-, samples = 200, thin, black, domain = -12:12 , name path=A] {0};          
    \addplot+[<-, samples = 200, thick, blue, domain = -11:-4 , name path=B] {0.5*(x + 4) + 4};       
    \addplot+[-, samples = 200, thick, blue, domain = -4:-0 , name path=C] {4};   
    \addplot+[-, samples = 200, thick, blue, domain = 0:6, name path=D] {-2*x+4};  
    \addplot+[->, samples = 200, thick, blue, domain = 6:10.25, name path=E] {4*(x - 6)-8};
    \addplot+[red, opacity = 0.3] fill between[of=A and B,soft clip={domain=-8:-4}]; % filling 
    \addplot+[red, opacity = 0.3] fill between[of=A and C,soft clip={domain=-4:-0}]; % filling    
    \addplot+[red, opacity = 0.3] fill between[of=A and D,soft clip={domain=0:6}]; % filling  
    \addplot+[red, opacity = 0.3] fill between[of=A and E,soft clip={domain=6:10}]; % filling                     
  \node[blue] at (axis cs:7,7){{\tiny$y = g(t)$}};            
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Single plot

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      axis lines=center,
      grid=major,
      xmin=-12.5,
      xmax=12.5,
      ymin=-10.5,
      ymax=10.5,
      xtick = {-12,-10,...,12}, 
      ytick = {-10,-8,...,10}, 
      yticklabel style = {font=\tiny,xshift=0.5ex},
      xticklabel style = {font=\tiny,yshift=0.5ex},
      no marks,
      axis line style={thick, <->},  
      ]
    \addplot+[<->, samples=200, thick, blue, name path=myplot] coordinates {
        (-11,.5) (-4,4) (0,4) (6,-8) (10.25,9)
    };
    \path[name path=axis] (axis cs:-10,0) -- (axis cs:12,0);
    \addplot+[red, opacity = 0.3] fill between[of=myplot and axis,soft clip={domain=-8:10}]; % filling                     
\node[blue] at (axis cs:7,7){{\tiny$y = g(t)$}};            
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the result in both cases is:

[image]

Comment: This makes sense and is much more practical. Thank you.

Comment: @Oiler Is the code finally working in your IDE?

Comment: Yes, it is working. The way that you plotted the function as well was very helpful. This is what I had in mind and it by passes the need to do mental math figuring out the equations of the lines.